# Has anybody tried meditating forehead to forehead? Or communicated with others via meditation?

Tags: meditation-effects, psychic-powers

I have been trying to hunt far and wide to see if anyone in the internet world has attempted meditating with someone else by connecting your foreheads together?

As discussed in a previous thread about the significance of touching foreheads, the sky-eye, upper dantian, sixth chakra, etc is a hugely powerful aspect of the body and referred to during prostrations and greetings.

I have only meditated with someone else like this once, in a temple and was certainly aware of the intense connection it could hold before I did it. However, I wasn't sure if anyone else has tried to do this, or does this often, and if so, why? What is your experience? I have also experienced this in dreams, as well as visualised doing this in meditation with someone else who has received it during their own meditation practice too (which I find pretty incredible!). I'd love to hear of any experiences where you have managed to connect with others in meditation too?

Comment: I giggled when I read this question.

Comment: @Xiao Long, as powerful as foreheads are, they are nothing compared to chests. When my guru hugged me once, my anahata was open all night like a giant pipe! :))

Comment: @yuttadhammo Me too, I literary planned to make the exact same comment, it is actually kind of funny when you picture it ;).

Comment: I think this question is irrelevant to this community. @yuttadhammo

Answer (score 4):

To be quite frank, I don't really see much point in this from a Buddhist perspective. What is the purpose in doing this? Maybe you can have some interesting experiences with different sensations, and for all I know, visions or psychic powers, but in the end these things don't lead towards awakening.

At most, these things could lead to a kind of concentration being developed, but there are other ways of developing concentration that can be used as part of the path. For example, one could develop the jhanas and then use them as a basis for examination. Practicing in that way would probably lead to a lot more pleasure than meditating on the chakras with your foreheads together, and it can be used to gain awakening.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The relation to Buddhist context is when you connect with the intention of Buddhist practice. For example, in Lucid Dreaming or Dream Yoga in the Tibetan tradition, it is possible to meet with other practitioners or your Lama(s) and practice the Dharma. Ideally, by connecting forehead to forehead, you can awaken aspects within yourself and within each other. I am not looking at this from a pleasure perspective, more to understand the potential of what could be.

Comment: @Xiao Even with the practice of Milam, or dream yoga, I would find it very strange that one would do anything touching the foreheads together. From my reading it seems that the use of the chakras in Milam only use the heart chakra or sometimes the throat chakra. I've never heard anything about the head. One thing to note is that in Tantric Buddhism, there are only 5 main chakras (center of head, throat, heart, navel, and root) so there is no main chakra near the forehead.

Comment: Because some who practice group meditation claim they're tapping into an invisible network between others in the space and at large. Maybe so. Or maybe they're delusional.

Answer (score 2):

In Buddhist meditation you have to do it more in seclusion (Sunyagara, under a tree, etc). There may be other techniques outside Buddhism (at least Theravada) where you may have pratices like this, but this practice does not conform to orthodox way meditation is done.

There is the practice of group meditation in certain Centres and Traditions but an healthy distance is maintained between the participants. This can sometimes be beneficial if you are experiencing agitation as near by meditators can influence your peace.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that meditation is done more in seclusion, I have been a practicing Buddhist for the majority of my life so this exploration in connecting in this way was somewhat 'new' to me and introduced to me via a teacher at the Kagyu school. It was more an experiment to see what would happen, especially whilst reciting mantra.

Answer (score 1):

Those things like `the sky-eye, upper dantian, sixth chakra` have more to with Qigong/Yoga than Buddhism if i'm not mistaken. Too be honest I've never seen/heard such a thing, and it's i'm not really sure it's connected with the Buddhist teachings in any way. It is practiced among [cats](http://catsbeaversandducks.tumblr.com/post/6407794161/head-to-head-meditation-only-for-masters-photo) however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right, these terms are mostly used within the Daoist context, as well as Tibetan. I was brought up as Dao Buddhist so it was a new concept for me to see when I saw my Lama greeting people in such a way. I was later taught about its significance and an old friend/teacher and I decided to see what could happen if we connected foreheads and recited mantra with positive intention and liberation of suffering. I became rather fascinated with the significance of foreheads connecting with other sentient beings and their behaviour, so wondered if anyone else had tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I experienced something I can only call some sort of dual or shared meditation with my now ex wife. We would sit for head to forehead and breath as we would in normal meditation and fall into these extremely long sessions of meditation where sense of time and surroundings disappeared. There was also a sensation we both described as being able see/feel the body of the other through our closed eyelids, almost like a outline or lines of faint light. There were also odd sensations where our hands or legs touched.

As we grew apart for a multitude of reasons, the occurrence faded and though we tried to reach the same state it became harder and harder. We did eventually separate, but we are still friends and close in a way, but neither of us has ever experienced something like this with another person.

Both of us seem to agree on having the fear we may never experience that with another. I am hoping that is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

I have a sencation in my eyes and fourhead when i touched soneone else is fourhead. If they have alot of energy i noticed the feeling is mire intense. I only noticed it by accident long ago lol. I still do not know why that happens. I recently put my hand on someones head and then felt that sencation. Still i di not know why that is. Maybe im sencative to energys ? I can only suspect.

Answer (score -1):

Yes indeed...few people will understand this... this should be done sitting or laying down foreheads touching with eyes closed... let the energy flow uninhibited between you & your partner ...don’t think, don’t anticipate... just feel ...remain open to give and to receive. This is a much deeper form of communication than human speech which is just a refined form of grunting.

Comment: BTW this can be done between any two receptive people... & it can also be done with other receptive creatures... I used to do it with a particular cat too.